# Present everything in a list in HTML Email

Tags: python

I've searched everywhere but I can't find a solution. How do I insert a list into HTML Email?

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4] # Can be longer and contain numbers and letters

# I have reduced my HTML Email code

html = """\
    {% for i in mylist%}
        <tr>
          <td> {{ i }} </td>
        </tr>
    {& endfor &}
""".format(mylist)
```

I've tried this but it does not work well.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance

Comment: "It does not work well"? What does that mean? Do you get errors? I assume this is Jinja2?

Comment: Can you set table elements without defining a table in the first place? You're setting rows and cells but you don't actually have a table

Comment: seemed to be unclear. check out my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103530/send-a-list-to-html-email

Answer (score 0):

`{% endfor %}` instead of `{& endfor &}`?

Comment: seemed to be unclear. check out my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103530/send-a-list-to-html-email

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a list to a string:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> str_mylist = str(mylist)
>>> str_mylist
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Add this string to your Mail:

```
html = """
        <tr>
          <td> %s  </td>
        </tr>
""" % str_mylist
```

Comment: It answers the question: How do I insert a list into HTML Email?; Edit: Added string insertion

Comment: Now you've lost the `for` loop. The edit is less effective. You're missing the templating language

Comment: seemed to be unclear. check out my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103530/send-a-list-to-html-email

Comment: Yes, sorry. I was confused by the native <string>.format() you are using and the loop stuff in the String, never seen that before. Where did you get the example? (maybe add this to your new question)