# Send a list to HTML Email

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am currently working with a HTML email document. Now I want to present a list with information from my database. How do I present the list in a HTML email? I've tried following:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

articles = ['hello', 2, 5, 'bye']

me = "email@gmail.com"
you = "email@gmail.com"
subject = 'something'

msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

html = """\

    {% for i in {articles} %}
        <p> {{ i }} </p>
    {% endfor %}

""".format(articles)

part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login("email@gmail.com", "password")

server.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me like you're trying to use the [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) synthax without knowing it.
You can either follow jinja2 Introduction in order to include it into your code, or just append `articles` to your html string with a simple loop, something like that:

```
articles = ['hello', 2, 5, 'bye']

html = """\
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
"""

rows = ""
for article in articles:
    rows = rows + "<tr><td>"+str(article)+"<td></tr>"
html = html.format(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks! But the "rows" should be above html.

Answer (score 0):

As noamyg mentioned, seems you want to use a jinja stlye template in your `html` variable, without using the package.

From the [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/intro/#basic-api-usage) documentation.

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('Hello {{ name }}!')
template.render(name='John Doe')
> 'Hello John Doe!'
```

So for your example import `jinja2`, use your `html` string as template and render it with your `articles` variable.